# How to do commit in bitbucket in parts?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have large commit therefore error when I try to do commit.
How I can do commit in parts?

Comment: What do you mean by error?

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: I get notice in terminal with a signal 9. Support told that is problem in large commit